# Set custom title on VerticalGridFragment on Android TV

Tags: android, android-tv

I'm trying to set custom `View` as a title for [`VerticalGridFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/VerticalGridFragment.html)

Here's the class I created:

```
public class MainTitleView extends RelativeLayout implements TitleViewAdapter.Provider {

    @BindView(R.id.top_logo)
    ImageView topLogo;

    private final TitleViewAdapter mTitleViewAdapter = new TitleViewAdapter() {
        @Override
        public View getSearchAffordanceView() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void setTitle(CharSequence titleText) {
            MainTitleView.this.setTitle(titleText);
        }

        @Override
        public void setBadgeDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        }

        @Override
        public void updateComponentsVisibility(int flags) {
        }
    };

    public MainTitleView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MainTitleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MainTitleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        View root  = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.main_title, this);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, root);
        topLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_logo_actionbar_white);
    }

    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        if (title != null) {
            topLogo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public TitleViewAdapter getTitleViewAdapter() {
        return mTitleViewAdapter;
    }
}
```

And then in my `VerticalGridFragment`:

```
setTitleView(new MainTitleView(getActivity()));
```

This doesn't work. I can see in debugger that constructor is called but I can't see anything attached to header. I couldn't find any examples of how to use this `TitleViewAdapter.Provider`.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you receive any kind of errors?

Comment: No. Just empty header...

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(android.support.v17.leanback.R.layout.lb_vertical_grid,
            container, false);
    ViewGroup gridFrame = (ViewGroup) root.findViewById(android.support.v17.leanback.R.id.grid_frame);
    installTitleView(inflater, gridFrame, savedInstanceState);
    getProgressBarManager().setRootView(root);
    return root;
}

@Override
public View onInflateTitleView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View title = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_title, parent, false);
    //initialize your custom title view here
    return title;
}
```

It's working for me. `R.layout.custom_title` just xml with single view (com.your.company.MainTitleView) with id `@+id/browse_title_group`.

Answer (score 0):

you only need to inflate your custom layout

```
 override fun onInflateTitleView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        parent: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        //initialize your custom title view here
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, parent, false)
    }
```

**Note:**
your root view id of the custom layout must be "browse_title_group" to work properly with scrolling